# Visual Studio Community ругаеться на действия с динамическим массивом!

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-studio

Задача состоит в том чтобы Написать динамический массив и с его помощью стек.
На вход подается n - длина массива, сам массив генерируеться случайно
есть два режима работы

a) Добавить новый элемент в конец

b) Убрать последний элемент

[image: Скриншот]

Проблема состоит в том, что после компиляции, во время работы программы Visual Studio прерывает работу и выдает ошибку, при изменении `array[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;` на `array[i] >> rand() % 100 + 1;` тоже ничего. Извините меня тупого, но в чем проблема, объясните пожалуйста, вроде бы ошибок в коде нет.

Вот сам текст программы:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef unsigned int uint;
using namespace std;

int *createArray(int* array, uint num)
{
    array = new int[num];
    return array;
}

int *fillArray(int* array, uint num)
{
    for (uint i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        array[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
    }
    return array;
}

void printArray(int* array, uint num)
{
    for (uint i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void deleteArray(int* array) 
{
    delete[] array;
}

int *addNewElement(int array[], uint num, int newData)
{
    int* temp = NULL;
    uint numTemp = num + 1;
    temp = createArray(temp, numTemp); // создаем временный массив
    for (uint i = 0; i < num; i++) temp[i] = array[i]; // копируем данные со старого массива
    temp[numTemp] = newData; // добавляем новый элемент в конец нового массива 
    deleteArray(array); // удаляем старый массив
    array = createArray(temp, numTemp);
    array = temp; //копируем временный массив в новый.
    deleteArray(temp); //удаляем временный массив
    return array;
}

uint deleteLastElement(int array[], uint num)
{
    int* temp = NULL;
    int numTemp = num - 1;
    temp = createArray(temp, numTemp);
    for (int i = 0; i < numTemp; i++) temp[i] = array[i]; // копируем данные со старого массива
    deleteArray(array); // удаляем старый массив
    array = createArray(temp, numTemp);
    array = temp; //копируем временный массив в новый.
    deleteArray(temp); //удаляем временный массив
    return array, num;
}

int main()
{
    // 1. Написать динамический массив и с его помощью стек.
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    uint num;
    int t;
    do
    {
        cout << "Ввдите целое число для определения длины массива..." << endl;
        std::cin >> num;
        if ((num >= 1) && (num <= 4294967295))
        {
            int* array = NULL;
            createArray(array, num);
            fillArray(array, num);
            cout << "Динамический массив успешно создан и заполнен случайными данными!" << endl;
            cout << "Для продолжения выберите дейстие\n a. Добавить новый элемент в конец. \n b. Убрать последний элемент" << endl;
            char mode;
            std::cin >> mode;
            if ((mode == 97) || (mode == 65)) // 97 is a, 65 is A
            {
                cout << "Данные в массиве: " << endl;
                printArray(array, num);
                int newData = (rand() % 100);
                addNewElement(array, num, newData);
                cout << "Новый сгенерированный элемент " << newData << " был добавлен в конец динамического массива" << endl;
                cout << "Данные в массиве: " << endl;
                printArray(array, num + 1);
            }
            if ((mode == 98) || (mode == 66)) // 98 is b, 66 is B
            {
                cout << "Данные в массиве: " << endl;
                printArray(array, num);
                uint Last_Elm = array[sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])]; // копируем значение последнего элемента для вывода
                deleteLastElement(array, num);
                cout << "Последний элемент " << array[Last_Elm] << "был удален из динамического массива" << endl;
                cout << "Данные в массиве: " << endl;
                printArray(array, num);
            }
            else
            {
                cout << endl << "Ошибка!" << endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << endl << "Ошибка!" << endl;
        }
        cout << "Хотите продолжить? да - 1; нет - 0" << endl;
        std::cin >> t;
        std::system("cls");
    } while (t != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Аргумент `int* array` — это непосредственно указатель на массив. То есть вы передаёте в функцию копию указателя, изменения которой теряются при выходе из функции (ибо она работает с копией):

```
// Копируем значение, переданное при вызове, в переменную «array». Эта переменная, по сути,
// локальная, то есть не имеет отношения к переменной «array» из main.
// Так как при вызове был передан NULL, то он и будет записан в переменную-копию.
int *createArray(int* array, uint num)
{
    // Теперь локальная переменная «array» указывает на копию
    array = new int[num];
    // Делаем ещё одну копию, на этот раз локальной переменной, и возвращаем её
    return array;
    // При выходе из функции локальная переменная «array» уничтожается; «array» из main
    // остаётся неизменным, сохраняя исходное значение NULL
}

// Как результат, при вызове fillArray() вы передаёте NULL, из-за чего происходит попытка
// записи по нулевому указателю, который по определению не указывает на какую-либо сущность
// в памяти. Как результат, операционная система аварийно завершает программу, обнаруживает
// логическую несогласованность ожиданий программиста и фактического поведения программы.
```

Решить проблему можно двумя способами:

1. Воспользоваться тем, что `createArray()` уже возвращает необходимый указатель.

   Было:

   ```
   int* array = NULL;
   createArray(array, num);
   ```

   Стало:

   ```
   int* array = createArray(NULL, num);
   ```

   Или даже:

   ```
   int *createArray(uint num)
   {
       int* array = new int[num];
       return array;
   }

   ...


   int* array = createArray(num);
   ```
2. Передавать в функцию копию не самого указателя на массив, а указателя на этот указатель, чтобы через него получить прямой доступ к исходной переменной:

   ```
   void createArray(int** array, uint num)
   {
       *array = new int[num];
   }

   ...

   int* array = NULL;
   createArray(&num);
   ```